# why netty can not make a distinction between socket close and socket half close

Tags: nio, netty

i got an interest problem, when i close (OIO) socket outputstream with half close manner, Netty server detect the event and trigger the ChannelClose method in handler, but in client side, the socket is open and connected, then i complete close socket in client, but this time, Netty server get no reflect.

doesn't it very strange?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your problem... Can you give some more details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody can tell the difference. Shutdown for output sends a FIN. Close sends a FIN, unless it has already been sent, i.e. by a shutdown. FIN appears at the receiver as the EOS (EOF) condition. The server got the FIN from the shutdown, saw that as EOS, closed the socket, your client got the FIN, saw that as EOS, closed the socket, and sent ... *nothing* to the server, because the FIN had already been sent.